# RDF/XML - correct syntax for classes

Tags: xml, rdf

Just trying to get my head round RDF statements. Given some namespaces:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:ex="http://example.org/#"
     xmlns:people="http://example.org/people/#"
>
```

Is there any difference between the statement:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="people:James_Brown">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="ex:person"> 
</rdf:Description>
```

and:

```
<ex:person rdf:resource="people:James_Browm" />
```

Comment: unless you're dead-set on learning RDF/XML syntax, can I recommend that you instead focus your energy on learning another syntax for RDF, like Turtle or N-Triples? These are so much more readable and compact. RDF/XML is not something you should ever need to write by hand.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not planning on writing it myself, but I have reasonably well tagged XML documents that I want to analyse with a view to saving  relationships and things in a triple store or graph database. I'm really just exploring the technologies to see how it all might work.

Answer (score 5):

With

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:ex="http://example.org/#"
     xmlns:people="http://example.org/people/#"
>
<ex:person rdf:resource="people:James_Browm" />
</rdf:RDF>
```

the [W3C validator](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/) returns:

```
Error: {E201} rdf:resource not allowed as attribute here.[Line = 6, Column = 48]
```

It should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:ex="http://example.org/#"
     xmlns:people="http://example.org/people/#"
>
<ex:person rdf:about="people:James_Browm" />
</rdf:RDF>
```

a RDF is a triple (subject,predicate,object) and  @resource is a URI for a subject.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of point your trying to make, but I'm pretty sure both of those statements are completely different from each other. Namespaces are usually prefixes that are attached to a tag like `<c:name>Bill Gates</c:name>` where the namespace in this case is c. You are trying to somehow combine namespaces into the value of your actual nodes which is not the right way to do it. Whenever you have something in quotes like `"people:James_Brown"` you are saying think about this whole statement as a value of this node. Hence any namespace reference you have inside is useless. A namespace is more used for grouping together a group of nodes, not trying to tag each data entry like you have done. I'd suggest surfing around and looking for some example XML docs to see the namespace/value relationship because I don't think what you have here is standard. Then again I'm also new and could be totally wrong.

Comment: Whoops - major knowledge gap. Thanks for the heads up.